# Requirements for TFS Nuget Package Restore

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have set the option on my VS2013 solution "Enable Nuget Package Restore" and its not restoring nuget packages on a build server. Plenty of missing references errors to System.Web.Mvc and so on...

Everything is fine on hosted TFS - but I'm running into issues with a secondary CI server using TeamCity. I don't have visual studio installed on the build server by choice.

I'd like to know how do I enable package restore on the build server.

I don't want the packages in source control and I'd like to avoid hosting my own nuget feed for the System.Web.Mvc etc..

Cheers!

Comment: have you tried using running nuget restore from command line

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across similar issue some time back, was able to resolve this by updating **RestorePackages** condition value to **True** in Nuget.Targets file.

Comment: I ended up making this setting and adding a custom build step in TC to install nuget packages directly.